# Remove rows where a specific column has a blank entry

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `Df` which looks like:

```
date        XNGS            BBG     FX
16/11/2007  19.41464766     0.6819  19.41464766
19/11/2007  19.34059332     0.6819  19.34059332
20/11/2007  19.49080536     0.6739  19.49080536
21/11/2007  19.2399259      0.673   19.2399259
22/11/2007                  0.6734  
23/11/2007  19.2009794      0.674   19.2009794
```

I would like to remove any rows where XNGS is empty.  In this example I would like to remove the row with the date index `22/11/2007`. So the resulting Df would look like:

```
    date        XNGS            BBG     FX
    16/11/2007  19.41464766     0.6819  19.41464766
    19/11/2007  19.34059332     0.6819  19.34059332
    20/11/2007  19.49080536     0.6739  19.49080536
    21/11/2007  19.2399259      0.673   19.2399259
    23/11/2007  19.2009794      0.674   19.2009794
```

The dataframe changes a lot so the fix needs to be dynamic.  I have tried:

```
Df = Df[Df.XNGS != ""]
```

and

```
Df.dropna(subset=["XNGS"])
```

but they don't work. What can I try next?

Comment: what's wrong with `Df = Df[Df.XNGS != ""]`?

Comment: I get the error  - 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'XNGS'

Comment: Please post an output of `print(Df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: Got a fix, Df["XNGS"].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
               Df.dropna(subset=["XNGS"], inplace=True)  Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Safe Option***
*canonical [**`dropna`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) after [**`replace`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)*

```
df.replace({'XNGS': {'': np.nan}}).dropna(subset=['XNGS'])

         date       XNGS     BBG         FX
0  16/11/2007  19.414648  0.6819  19.414648
1  19/11/2007  19.340593  0.6819  19.340593
2  20/11/2007  19.490805  0.6739  19.490805
3  21/11/2007  19.239926  0.6730  19.239926
5  23/11/2007  19.200979  0.6740  19.200979
```

***Less Safe, but Cool***
*Empty strings evaluate to `False`*

```
df[df.XNGS.values.astype(bool)]

         date       XNGS     BBG         FX
0  16/11/2007  19.414648  0.6819  19.414648
1  19/11/2007  19.340593  0.6819  19.340593
2  20/11/2007  19.490805  0.6739  19.490805
3  21/11/2007  19.239926  0.6730  19.239926
5  23/11/2007  19.200979  0.6740  19.200979
```

---

***Timing***
*small data*

```
%timeit (df.replace({'XNGS': {'': np.nan}}).dropna(subset=['XNGS']))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.39 ms per loop

%timeit df[df.XNGS.values.astype(bool)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 192 µs per loop
```

*large data*

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit (df.replace({'XNGS': {'': np.nan}}).dropna(subset=['XNGS']))
100 loops, best of 3: 10.5 ms per loop

%timeit df[df.XNGS.values.astype(bool)]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.11 ms per loop
```

Comment: May I ask why the `astype` solution is *less safe*?

Answer (score 0):

What about query?

```
Df.query('XNGS != ""', inplace=True)
```

or

```
Df = Df.query('XNGS != ""')
```

Answer (score 0):

A long way of doing it is:

```
df["column name"].fillna(9999, inplace=True)
df = df[df["column name"]!= 9999]
```

Comment: What is the benefit of doing this?

Comment: Its a safe and easy way of doing.